# How to make regular expression for (A102, S331, A4021, A501, S6021)?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to filter `<input>` tag. So `<input>` tag can only accept special formula.
Here is formula and code I've tried.

**Formula:**

```
ex1:    A100, A200, S321, S600, S712
ex2:    S101, S3091, A9012, A9321, S8001
```

**Code**

```
function processExpression(expression) {
   let expression = expression.replace(/\s+/g, '');

   if (!/^(\d+)?(?:,(\d+))*$/.test(expression)) {
     // fail case
     return false;
   }

   // success case
   return true;
}
```

My current code works without `A` and `S` now. For example `101, 201, 330, 1212, 2123`

But it doesn't works for `A` or `S`. For example `A102, S331, A4021, A501, S6021`

How can I do it? Please anyone help.

Comment: Why not just add an `[AS]` character class prior to your `\d+` match?

Comment: `^(\d+)` will match only if the string starts with a  digit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex should work for your validation:

```
/^[AS]\d+$/
```

This allows any string starting with `A` or `S`, followed by one or more digits.

Use this in case you want to allow any uppercase letter at the start:

```
/^[A-Z]\d+$/
```